# Trouble to get pivot in dTale to work without error

Tags: python, pandas, pypi

Under Anaconda 2.1.2 using dTale 2.1.0 try to analyze a simple dataframe and encounter prettz blatant errors. Here's the dataset:

[image]

Launch "Summarize Data" and specify "Pivot" with the following parameters:
[image]

However, then I click "Execute" get the following error:
[image]

Would appreciate some assistance of how I have gotten what is ostensibly a simple transformation totally wrong.

TIA - John

Comment: Appears to be a problem with use of **dtale** within a **Jupyter notebook**. When I use dtale directly in python interpreter, operations seem to work as expected. _**Would be good to understand how to get this to work under Jupyter notebooks.**_

Comment: Revision. Appears to be a "common problem" as many of the on-line dtale datasets suffer from the same problem. Not clear whether it is a problem with most recent releases of the package or dreaded package conflict. Appears that lots of folks "blog" about the package; but not so many are encountering issues that I am. Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

Appears that this is indeed a bug with “front-end”. Rolling back until version prior to 2.0.0 should provide intermediate fix until next release. May also need to use alternative browser as in my case one browser was more error prone to this than another.